# Map value encode and decode

Tags: java, dictionary, utf-8, decode, encode

I need to encode the map value and get it back decoded. The below code doesn't decode the value.

```
    byte[] bytes = "This,is,test".getBytes("UTF-8");
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("description",bytes);

    String s1= map.toString();
    String s2[]=s1.substring(1,s1.length()-1).split("=");
    String string1 = new String(s2[1].getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(string1);
```

Comment: Uhm, why do you want to do that exactly?

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println(s1)` to your program, see what it prints out ... What do you expect `map.toString()` to return? What do you expect it would do if there were more than one entry in the map?

Comment: do you want to make json string from your map and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

`map.toString()` is going to use the `toString()` representation of the `byte[]`, which does not contain any information about its contents: it refers to the identity hash of the byte array.

It is impossible to recover the `byte[]` contents from `byte[].toString()`, or in your case, from the `toString()` of the map.

Comment: Is there any other way it can be achieved? I need to read the map again and decode the map value.

Comment: If you want to extract the `byte[]` information, you're going to have to convert the `Map` to a `String` some other way besides `map.toString()`, or you're going to have to store something other than a `byte[]`.